# MySQL Error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: mysql, apache-superset

Mariadb 10.5

Python 3.8

Superset 2.0

MariaDB and Superset are both deployed in K8S cluster.

I wanted to connect Superset with my Airflow backend DB (MariaDB ) and display data in Superset, just to test it.

In order to connect superset with MariaDB , I created connection using MSSQL driver.
I was able to connect and view the list of databases, tables and columns but when I tried to query the data , **regardless to which table or column I selected** , I received an error

[image]

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/app/superset/views/base.py", line 207, in wraps
>     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/app/superset/utils/log.py", line 245, in wrapper
>     value = f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/app/superset/views/core.py", line 2395, in sql_json
>     command_result: CommandResult = command.run()   File "/app/superset/sqllab/command.py", line 114, in run
>     raise ex   File "/app/superset/sqllab/command.py", line 98, in run
>     status = self._run_sql_json_exec_from_scratch()   File "/app/superset/sqllab/command.py", line 151, in
> _run_sql_json_exec_from_scratch
>     raise ex   File "/app/superset/sqllab/command.py", line 146, in _run_sql_json_exec_from_scratch
>     return self._sql_json_executor.execute(   File "/app/superset/sqllab/sql_json_executer.py", line 111, in execute
>     raise SupersetErrorsException( superset.exceptions.SupersetErrorsException:
> [SupersetError(message="invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''",
> error_type=<SupersetErrorType.GENERIC_DB_ENGINE_ERROR:
> 'GENERIC_DB_ENGINE_ERROR'>, level=<ErrorLevel.ERROR: 'error'>,
> extra={'engine_name': 'MySQL', 'issue_codes': [{'code': 1002,
> 'message': 'Issue 1002 - The database returned an unexpected
> error.'}]})]
```

I also tried to connect with **SQLALCHEMY URI**
mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@ip:3306/airflow_db
I was able to connect but same error!

Any idea why?

Comment: Both error messages (on the screenshot and in the log) are NOT MySQL error messages. Try to find in the program what is errorneous value and why it is used.

Answer (score 0):

This error message (python error "`MySQL Error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`") is a consequence of an underlying Mysql connection error as you may find in the error log. The SQL result failed due to some connection error and the app is expecting some integer value, getting `''` (empty string)

Superset Error 1002
https://superset.apache.org/docs/miscellaneous/issue-codes/#issue-1002

Follow the instructions from this page https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/db-connection-ui/ to check your MYSQL connection parameters.